# Postgresql : decrypt column only once when used in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, encryption

I have the following request, using pg_trm and gin index:

```
SELECT
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name
         
    FROM   external_patient
    WHERE  PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY') ILIKE $2
    OR     PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY') %     $1
    ORDER  BY 
           (PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY') ILIKE $3) DESC
          ,(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY') ILIKE $2) DESC
          ,(PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY') <->   $1)
          ,PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY')
    LIMIT  30
```

the column cat_name is encrypted, so it has to be decrypted to run the request.
However, I want to make sure it is decrypted only once if possible (as the request is 3ms without an encrypted field, and 3500 ms with encryption...

Is there a specific syntax to make sure this column is decrypted only once?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which version of Postgres? Perhaps you could try a CTE.

Comment: You must be aware that making operations (decrypt) in the WHERE clause will result in a table full-scan. If you expect less than 1000 rows it should no be a time problem.

Comment: This is using Postgresql version 11

Comment: Thank you @hschou, this is what I'm afraid of... That all my indexes are ignored when using an encrypted column. My table is currently 10K entries but could grow to 30k or more, so the request duration would grow accordingly :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your decrypted column to the SELECT and wrap that into a derived table:

```
select email, first_name, last_name
from (
    SELECT email,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY')   as cat_name_decrypted
    FROM   external_patient
) t
WHERE cat_name_decrypted ILIKE $2
   OR cat_name_decrypted %     $1
ORDER  BY 
       (cat_name_decrypted ILIKE $3) DESC
      ,(cat_name_decrypted ILIKE $2) DESC
      ,(cat_name_decrypted <->   $1)
      ,cat_name_decrypted
LIMIT  30
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try this and comment on the result!

Comment: This works well - though there's no change at all in performance. I guess postgresql was smart enough to optimize out the multiple calls to PGP_SYM_DECRYPT. Then, as mentioned by @hschou , the index is not used anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This solution will call `PGP_SYM_DECRYPT()` for all rows anyway. `ILIKE` is also a function.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a new column (or 3) with a hash of the search. It take up some space but you only decrypt once.

```
ALTER TABLE external_patient
ADD COLUMN cat_name_hash TEXT;

UPDATE external_patient
SET cat_name_hash = SHA256(LOWER(email || first_name || last_name));

SELECT
   email,
   first_name,
   last_name, 
   PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(cat_name::bytea, 'SUPER_AES_KEY') as cat_name_decrypted
WHERE cat_name_hash = SHA256(LOWER($1));
```

Here `SHA256()` and `LOWER()` is in the where clause but is only calculated once. The `$1` should be the search triplet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here...
It looks like you are doing an exact match on the triplet email first_name last_name (or on its hash), which is not what I'm trying to do. Indeed, I wanted to use pg_trm and a gin index to do an approximate match and return a list of results, sorted from best score to lowest score. 'Google search as you type' style.

Comment: Oh 'best score'?. This can't be done without a full-scan.